# How can I configure my firewall to block Abobe Illustrator CC 2014 updates on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall, adobe-illustrator

I have a very simple question. How can I configure my firewall to block Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 updates on Windows 7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to create a Windows Firewall rule. Go to **Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Windows Firewall**. Click **Advanced settings** on the right-hand side, click **Outbound rules** on the left-hand side, then click **New Rule** on the right.

[image]

On the next window, make sure you have **Program** selected and click **Next**. Select the button for **This program path:** and click **Browse**. From here, you'll need to navigate to the .EXE file for Illustrator. It'll be under **C:\Program Files (x86)** (w/o the x86 if you're not running 64-bit Windows) and possibly within the Adobe sub-folder.

Once you've found the .EXE file, click **Next**, Block the **connection**, apply it to **Domain/Private/Public** networks, give it a name, and click **Finish**.

Comment: Thanks. I've blocked the `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2014\Adobe Ilustrator CC 2014.exe` which is a Windows link to `%ProgramFiles%\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2014\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe`. This should do it. Thanks.